# Implement key loading with cen-xfs API

Tags: cen-xfs

does anyone happens to know how to use XFS API to update ATM encryption keys (such as 32 characters clear key pairs) ?

I have read CWA16374 documents but not sure how to use the API since there is some many commands involved (which command to call and how)

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Sadly CEN XFS standard is not covering all the aspects and at least some of the key manipulations needs to be done using the manufacturer specific APIs.

I only have experience from NCR crypto module, and it doesn't sound like you use one of those.

So you'll need to go through the Hardware providers manuals to get hang of it.

Comment: well right now I'm willing to take a look on anything if you could share it, since they design xfs for interoperability there is high chances that it works on other hardware, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the msxfs.dll to access the XFS devices (in your case, I think this device will be PIN specification). All XFS devices works using the same API interface defined in msxfs.dll. You have a WFSStartUp command to start XFS Manager communication, a WFSOpen command to open a sesion with a specific device (The PIN in your case, a cash dispenser, a card reader, etc). Once you have access with WFSOpen, you need to execute WFSExecute or WFSGetInfo commands to access the device. For this you need the PIN API documentation (public in internet). This documentation describes the commnands you can execute using WFSExecute and WFSGetInfo XFS commands. There is a standard specification for each financial device type in the market. For keys, encryptions, etc, you have the PinPad device (a keyboard, key stored and cypher operations)

There are a lot of things to explain about it, but I think this would be a good starting point.

Here you have the starndard documentation:

https://www.cen.eu/work/areas/ICT/eBusiness/Pages/WS-XFS.aspx